# Core data model - relationships

Tags: core-data

I am confused about how to design a Core Data Model for a particular trio of entities -- specifically,  the relationships between them.

"Place" is an entity comprised of a name (String) and an address (String).

"Leg" is an entity comprised of a start (Place) and an end (Place).

"Route" is an entity comprised of an arbitrary number of legs (Leg) in a particular order.

In sum, a Route consists of an ordered list of Legs which themselves simply represent straight lines between two Places.

How would I model the relationship between the Leg and Place entities in the data model?  Each Leg has exactly two Places (start and end); and any Place could be associated with an unlimited number of Legs, either as a start or an end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the **Leg** entity Add two relationships , one for startPlace and another for endPlace , make their type **"To One"**
2. In the **Place** entity add two **inverse** relationships (legsByStartPlaceInverse and legsByEndPlaceInverse) and make their type **"To Many"**.
3. Make sure delete rules are **not** "Cascade".

Comment: Ok, so adopting this approach I would:

1.  In the Route entity add one inverse relationship, called "legs", of type "To Many";

2.  In the Leg entity add one relationship, called "routesByLegInverse", of type "To Many".

Seem correct?

Comment: Yes, the Route and Leg entities has Many-To-Many relationship.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution and it seems to be working well in my project.